# Can an absolute element appear above padding/margin of a parent?

Tags: position, containers, margin, padding, absolute

In this application, I have a modal with 30px padding. Inside of this modal , I have a checkbox that has a focused state which creates a circle around the checkbox that has position: absolute. The problem is that the left side of this circle gets cut off as soon as it hits the padding of the modal. Is there any way around this outside of redesigning the structure of the checkbox so that is doesn't require a position: absolute circle around it?

```
<div class="content--container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</div>

.content--container {
    padding: 30px;
}

.checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: -7px;
    top: -3px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 34px;
}
```